# Actively Refused Connections

Tags: java, visual-studio, apache, tomcat, socketexception

I know this question has been asked several times before, but my case is a little odd.

I have a machine listening to X.X.X.X:8080, which acts as a load-balancer and redirects requests to two other machines, listening to port 8081. When I run the program, there are no bugs or errors; it's a simple app.

The problem comes when I'm trying to test it out for load-testing. I'm using a Web Performance and Load Test via Visual Studio 2012, and I've recorded the WebTest routes correctly (as far as I know). But when I run a load-test with anything over 200 users, the error report generated shows this error:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it X.X.X.X:8080."

And the queer thing is, exactly 1,000 of these errors show up every time, no more no less. Anything below 200 users and I get other errors, which I can figure out, but this really has me on my hair's end.

I am using Tomcat, and Apache HTTPD Server in front of it.

Help!

Comment: Just a quick comment, you might have get better answers to this question on [ServerFault StackExchange](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Is there anything like `MaxClients 200` in your httpd config? Or if it is smaller than 200 does it help to increase that value?